# Move all the zeros in the given array at the end of array, modifying the existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Given an integer array nums, move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.
Example 1:

Input: nums = `[0,1,0,3,12]`
Output: `[1,3,12,0,0]`
Example 2:

Input: nums = [0]
Output: [0]

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] === 0) {
      nums.splice(i, 1);
      nums.push(0);
    }
  }
  return nums;
};
```

the given code works for the

```
[0,1,0,3,12]
```

but does not work for

```
[0,0,1]
```

it returns

```
[0,1,0]
```

Comment: When you splice an element, the contents of the array shift, but you haven't adjusted your index, essentially skipping over values that may need to be moved. I would suggest starting at the end of your array and working your way backward.

Comment: `filter()` out the zeroes, then add them back at the end. The number of 0's to add back is the difference in length of the original array and the filtered array.

Comment: `[0,1,0,3,12].sort((a,b) => !b - !a)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code code is that it doesn't handle multiple consecutive zeros correctly. When it encounters a zero, it removes and pushes it to the end, but then it continues iterating without considering that the next zero might have been shifted to the current index. To fix this, I think we can decrement the index 'i' when a zero is encountered. I modified your code, here it is:

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
   for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] === 0) {
        nums.splice(i, 1);
        nums.push(0);
        i--; // Decrement i to handle consecutive zeros
      }
   }
   return nums;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```js
const moveZeroes  = array => {
  return  [
    ...array.filter(int => int),
    ...array.filter(int => ! int)
   ];
}

const testArray1 = [0,1,5,0,3,6,-2,66,0,2,57,0,-54];

const testArray2 = [0,1,0,3,12];

const testArray3 = [0,0,1]; 



document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
JSON.stringify( moveZeroes(testArray1) ) + '<br>' +
JSON.stringify( moveZeroes(testArray2) ) + '<br>' +
JSON.stringify( moveZeroes(testArray3) ) + '<br>';
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```